# Character frequency scoring operation

Tags: cryptography, xor

The cryptography challenge as stated at https://cryptopals.com/sets/1/challenges/3
is :

```
Single-byte XOR cipher
The hex encoded string:

1b37373331363f78151b7f2b783431333d78397828372d363c78373e783a393b3736
... has been XOR'd against a single character. Find the key, decrypt the message.

You can do this by hand. But don't: write code to do it for you.

How? Devise some method for "scoring" a piece of English plaintext. Character frequency is a good metric. Evaluate each output and choose the one with the best score.
```

Is the solution to this ? :

As the inverse of XOR is XOR should I XOR the string 1b37373331363f78151b7f2b783431333d78397828372d363c78373e783a393b3736 with each character in range `a-z` but how should I score this string ? How is character frequency related to score ?

Answer (score 4):

Note that the string is in hexadecimal, so you must interpret it as a series of hexadecimal characters (presumably [ascii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Code_chart) encoding).

#### Before Encoding

```
1b37373331363f78151b7f2b783431333d78397828372d363c78373e783a393b3736

1b 37 37 33 31 36 3f 78 
15 1b 7f 2b 78 34 31 33
3d 78 39 78 28 37 2d 36
3c 78 37 3e 78 3a 39 3b
37 36
```

#### After Encoding

```
77316?x+x413=x9x(7-6<x7>x:9;76

   7  7  3  1  6  ?  x
   +     x     4  1  3
=  x  9  x  (  7  -  6
<  x  7  >  x  :  9  ;
7  6
```

## What About Scoring?

Scoring is basically comparing the output to what we expect the output to look like, and is a very important concept in developing what are formally called *heuristics*; educated guesses/solutions to a problem.

In English, certain letters are significantly more common than any others. 'e' is often quoted as the most frequent letter in English text. A frequency table of letters allows you to check if a string is likely to be English. In other words, to *score* any guesses you have when you decrypt the string.

For fun, you could write a program to make frequency tables. It would scan plaintext (this answer for example), tally each letter, and then show the percentage of the text which uses the letter. After putting together enough samples, you'll have your very own frequency table! If you don't want to compile your own, then consult the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency), or search for other information.

Another thing to notice is that we're missing some data when we convert to ascii. Some of the data became special characters that cannot be displayed. This presents another possible scoring mechanism; some special characters would not appear in strings typed by keyboard, so a string using many of these is unlikely to be correct.

## How to write the code?

As for how to code the solution, you'll want to xor each hexadecimal character by each ascii character in the range of `a-z`. Note that 'each' is used twice, so you will probably have two `for` statements or looping constructs in your code.

Depending on how your `XOR` function is implemented, a clever way to reduce iterations may be to copy the single ascii character enough times to match the length of the string, then `XOR` the two values.

Here I XOR by ascii 'a':

```
Input:
    1b37373331363f78151b7f2b783431333d78397828372d363c78373e783a393b3736
Length of input:
    34
Repeat (a in ascii) by length:
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
Then XOR:
    input
    repeat
Output:
    zVVRPW^tzJUPR\XIVLW]V_[XZVW
```

---

### EDIT:

Seeing as a very long time has passed, I have implemented a solution in python for posterity.

```
import string
import re

in_hex = '1b37373331363f78151b7f2b783431333d78397828372d363c78373e783a393b3736'


def take(n, s):
    '''yield n-sized chunks from iterable s'''
    for i in range(0, n, 2):
        yield s[i:i+2]


def hex2str(s):
    '''given an ascii string of single-byte hex literals, interpret as ascii'''
    return bytes.fromhex(s).decode('ascii')


def string_xor(s, c):
     '''given an ascii string s of hexadecimal values, xor each one by char c'''
     c = ord(c)  # dirty dynamic typing
    return ''.join(map(lambda h: chr(ord(h) ^ c), s))


for letter in string.ascii_letters:
    result = string_xor(hex2str(in_hex), letter)
    # remove ascii control chars
    pretty_result = re.sub(r'[\x00-\x1F]+', '', result)
    # print the result and the corresponding letter used to decode
    print(f'{letter}: {pretty_result}')
```

The successful line:

```
X: Cooking MC's like a pound of bacon
```